# Need Default CSS Button (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used a tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp to use jQuery to allow visitors to change styles. I created two buttons, one which allows visitors to change the font to Georgia, another to change the background and font colors.

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#btn24").click(function(){
        $(".Page1").css({"font-family":"Georgia"});
        $("header").css({"font-family":"Arial"});
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#btn25").click(function(){
        $(".Page1").css({"background-color":"black","color":"fff"});
    });
});
</script>

<button id="btn24" style="background: #900; font-family: Georgia;">Georgia</button>
<button id="btn25" style="background: #000;">Black</button>
```

Now I'm ready for the next step - allowing users to return to the default style. Are there ways to remove the styles invoked by a button, two or more buttons or all buttons?

Comment: No, use classes to add the styles and remove the classes for the 'default' styles.

Comment: look a simply way in my opinion is to make 2 css files with default and additional .. and give your <link class=""> a class and change href for it in button click event

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply create a few css styles that aren't used initially. If the button is pressed, add a class to the `body`. You need to use that class in the css styles too. (So have a style `.specialClass button` for example, where `specialClass` is the class you assign to the body when you want to set the special styles on)

If you want to remove the additional layout, remove the css class with a button and it will return to default.

Comment: I think I understand; the tutorial I cited discusses adding and removing classes, too. However, I don't understand how you create CSS styles that aren't included by default. If I have a CSS style in my head section or on a stylesheet I'm linked to, then it will be a part of the food chain. How do I create a style that isn't included by default?

Comment: By prefixing it with a class you initially don't use. See the sample between parentheses in my answer.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. In my HTML, I might have the following code: <div class="first">. But my style sheet might have two styles, .first and .second. I can then use JQuery to change my html to <div class="first second">. I'll give that a try. Thx!